# Using a timestamp from a df to slice another df in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I am trying to use 2 timestamps from a data frame to extract (slice) a subset from a different dataframe where those timestamps are included as indexes. Here is what I've tried.

```
In [152]: wt_filtered.head()
Out[152]: 
             start_time            end_time  tot_PR
81  2013-07-13 05:00:00 2013-07-13 07:00:00   0.015
164 2013-10-31 19:00:00 2013-10-31 21:00:00   0.030
234 2013-12-09 16:00:00 2013-12-09 18:00:00   0.015
295 2014-01-11 02:00:00 2014-01-11 07:00:00   0.060
325 2014-02-05 17:00:00 2014-02-05 19:00:00   0.015
```

And this is my second dataframe:

```
In [160]: my_df.head()
Out[160]: 
                     ValidLevel  ValidVelocity  ...  GW_Level     PR
DateTime                                        ...                 
2013-06-07 00:00:00        2.07           0.91  ...    444.74  0.000
2013-06-07 01:00:00        2.01           0.46  ...    444.74  0.010
2013-06-07 02:00:00        1.82           0.54  ...    444.74  0.005
2013-06-07 03:00:00        1.98           0.68  ...    444.74  0.005
2013-06-07 04:00:00        1.92           0.59  ...    444.74  0.015
```

I want to extract data from the second data frame using the start_time and end_time as parameters in the slicing process.

I tried this:

```
my_df[wt_filtered.start_time[0]:wt_filtered.end_time[0]]
```

And did not work. Maybe I am overlooking something but cannot find the answer.

I want to get something like this:

```
DateTime             ValidLevel  ValidVelocity  ...  GW_Level     PR                 
2013-07-13 05:00:00        1.24           0.99  ...    445.06  0.005
2013-07-13 06:00:00        1.29           1.51  ...    445.08  0.005
2013-07-13 07:00:00        1.57           1.44  ...    445.11  0.005
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good practice for this situation is to access the df's data using `.loc` and `.iloc` method:

```
my_df.loc[wt_filtered.start_time.iloc[0]:wt_filtered.end_time.iloc[0],:]
```

Hope it is useful

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solved the problem. I was missing the .iloc piece of it.